# Weaky converging sequence is equiintegrable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Given $p\in(1,+\infty]$, let $(u_{n})\subseteq L^{p}(E)$ and $u\in L^{p}(E)$ be such that $u_{n}\rightharpoonup u$ if $p\neq+\infty$ ($u_{n}$ converges weakly) and $u_{n}\overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} u$ if $p=+\infty$ ($u_{n}$ is weakly* star convergent), with $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ measurable with finite measure.

Show $u_{n}$ is an equiintegrable family.

We me try the criterion: $u_{n}\rightharpoonup u$ if and only if:

1. $u_{n}$ is bounded
2. $\int_{E}u_{n}\varphi\rightarrow \int_{E}u\varphi\quad$ for all $\varphi\in L^{1-\frac{1}{p}}(E)$

criterion which holds also for $u_{n}\overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} u$, plus the density of simple functions in $L^{p}$ with $p\neq+\infty$ but I'm not able to finish the proof

Comment: $\int_E|u_n| \le \Vert u_n\Vert_p (m(E))^{1/q}$, where ${1\over p}+{1\over q}=1$.

Comment: Shouldn't we show $\int_{E}|u_{n}|dx$ is magiorized by an arbitrary constant $\varepsilon>0$? Then norm of $u_{n}$ times the measure of $E$ to an index is rather arbitrary, so I don't understand how this shows it is equiintegrable.

Comment: $(u_n)$ is norm-bounded and $m(E)^{1/q}$ can be made as small as you wish.

Comment: The $p = 1$ case is more interesting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems